# Tensorflow string_input_producer misbehave when num_epochs is set

Tags: tensorflow

string_input_producer doesn't seem to enqueue string when the num_epochs is set.

With the following code, the program print [0], which is not right.

```
`import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
filenames = ["1", "2", "3"]
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=10)
test_value = tf.convert_to_tensor(filename_queue.size())

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

print(sess.run([test_value]))`
```

But if I take out num_epochs,

```
`import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
filenames = ["1", "2", "3"]
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
test_value = tf.convert_to_tensor(filename_queue.size())

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

print(sess.run([test_value]))`
```

It prints [3] as expected.

Is there anyone else encounter the same issue?

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. I think your best option is to open an issue on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the line:

```
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

...before starting the queue runners. The [`tf.train.string_input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer) function creates a [TensorFlow variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) internally to track the current epoch index, and it must be initialized before its first use (which will be when you start the queue runners).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, use

> sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

before starting the queue runners.
Because the [tf.train.string_input_producer()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/input_pipeline#string_input_producer) creates local counter if num_epochs is not None.